# Return all documents only if all matches conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Looking for help with a query that returns either true or false (or an empty array when false or similar) I need to query a couple of documents `by id` in a collection and only return true if all documents match the query, if one or more documents don't match I need a false value returned.

If the documents looks like below with the checked value both true and false I would like a false/empty array value back from the query but if the checked are true in all I want a true or the whole array back.

If a regular `find` is more suitable i could use that.

I've tried with a regular $match but it only return the matched documents.

I do like this now but feels it could be done in a better way?

```
 const coupons = await CouponModel.find({ id }, { checked: 1, _id: 0 });

 const everyCouponIsChecked = coupons.every(data => data.checked === true);
```

Thanks.

```
Sample data:

[ { _id: 5e43e7831bc81503efa54c61,
    id: 'foo',
    checked: true,
},
{ _id: 5e43e7831bc81503efa54c61,
    id: 'foo',
    checked: true,
},{ _id: 5e43e7831bc81503efa54c61,
    id: 'foo',
    checked: false,
}]


const result = await MyModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        id: 'foo',
        checked: true,

      },
    },

  ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a $group stage with null _id, then check if all elements checked field are true with [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/) operator.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      allTrue: {
        $allElementsTrue: "$docs.checked"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              true,
              "$allTrue"
            ]
          },
          then: "$docs",
          else: "$allTrue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If any checked field is false, result will equal to false, else result will be equal to the array of documents.

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dFyAsbN-11x)

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a query like this

```
const coupons = await CouponModel.find({ _id:id, checked:true });
const everyCouponIsChecked = coupons.length > 0;
```